# Spago Bi webservice cal to get the datasets

Tags: business-intelligence

I am new to Spago bi and my requirement is to get the list of available data sets with the spagoBI using spago sdk . Any help on how to use the sdk or any sample would be really helpful

I tried this

```
    String user1 = "biadmin";
    String password1 = "biadmin";
    try {
     DataSetsSDKServiceProxy proxy = new DataSetsSDKServiceProxy(user1, password1);
     proxy.setEndpoint("http://localhost:8080/SpagoBI/sdk/DataSetsSDKService");

     SDKDataSet[] datasets = proxy.getDataSets();
     System.out.println("*** dataset: " + datasets.length);
    }  catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
```

But i am getting the following exception

org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in it.eng.spagobi.sdk.datasets.bo.SDKDataSet - active
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in it.eng.spagobi.sdk.datasets.bo.SDKDataSet - active
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail:

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same, I have modified your code just a little bit and I confirm it is ok.
Therefore, I would think it is due to the web service or maybe it is caused by a conflict in anywhere else..Do you have the SpagoSDK running up on your server? Did you check the logs on Tomcat?..I mean coul you put more info?

Anyway, I am putting my code and the response (Linux + SpagoBI 5)

```
import it.eng.spagobi.sdk.datasets.bo.SDKDataSet;
import it.eng.spagobi.sdk.proxy.DataSetsSDKServiceProxy;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String user1 = "biadmin";
        String password1 = "biadmin";

        try {
            DataSetsSDKServiceProxy proxy = new DataSetsSDKServiceProxy(user1, password1);
            proxy.setEndpoint("http://localhost:8080/SpagoBI/sdk/DataSetsSDKService");

            SDKDataSet[] datasets = proxy.getDataSets();
            System.out.println("*** dataset: " + datasets);
            System.out.println("*** num of dataset: " + datasets.length);

            for (int i = 0; i < datasets.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("*** Description: " + datasets[i].getName());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting the next response (my own datasets), so it is working

```
run:
*** dataset: [Lit.eng.spagobi.sdk.datasets.bo.SDKDataSet;@dd8bec
*** num of dataset: 10
*** Name: test
*** Name: test_chart
*** Name: txs_st
*** Name: txs st2
*** Name: EXCEL_PERSIST
*** Name: excel test
*** Name: excel test optim
*** Name: excel test optim bar
*** Name: SIMPLE BAR CHART TEST
*** Name: SIMPLE_BAR_CHART
```

Bye